# How to update a twitter widget in meteor without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor. I have a template that associate a specific question with a specific twitter timeline widget. I got the data ({{question}},{{questionanwser}},{{tweetid}})  from the iron router data function.

The twitter widget load normally on the first question. I can switch between questions by clicking on a button and the content is correctly updated, however the twitter widget by itself does not change.  I can only update the widget with the correct twitterid if I reload the page.

Question.html:

```
<template name="question">
<h3>{{question}}:</h3>
<p>{{questionanwser}}</p>
{{> twitter}}
</template>
```

Twitter.html:

```
<template name="twitter"> 
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/test"
data-widget-id="{{tweetid}}">
Tweets 
</a>  
</template>
```

Twitter.js:

```
Template.twitter.onRendered(function(){
        ! function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
});
```

I have tried several things in order to make the widget to update without a reload of the page but nothing have worked so far. On twitter developers page, they suggest to use `twttr.widgets.load()`but I am not sure how to use that in this specific configuration. 
I have also try to make the onRendered template reactive by including `this.autorun` with a `session.get` but it didn't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?